# Infix return if operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, operator-keyword, operation, infix-notation

I have much of validation like this

```
if (someBoolean) return
```

Can I create an infix operator with following syntax?

```
returnif someBoolean
```

Comment: Would that be a good idea? Would others reading the code understand it or would it be a WT? moment for them? Some say that code should be written for easy comprehension by others--or even one's-self in the future.

Comment: Is a switch statement applicable?

Comment: `returnif someBoolean` reminds me of `goto fail` where `fail` is the end of the function (which Dijkstra explicit allows). The explicit brackets on an if statement were added to Swift to avoid this kind of potential error. Also `if (someBoolean) return` is not valid Swift code.

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea, and I would strongly recommend you don't do it. Zaph's logic seems sound.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. It seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't write this operator (which would be prefix rather than infix), for two reasons:

- operators can't be defined with alphanumeric characters (see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418) for a rundown of what they can be defined with)
- you can't write a function (which is what custom operators are) that results in a return in it's calling scope i.e. return within the operator function would just return from the operator function, not from the function you used the operator in